# How to get the Latitude and Longitude from a address using the google geocode API?

Tags: javascript, google-geocoding-api

Creating a weather app to learn JavaScript. I have managed to get the weather from OpenWeatherMap API for the location of the computer when the pages loads based on latitude and longitude, Then I have a drop down box that autofills using google places API, then I have a submit button where I want to convert the name of the place into the latitude and longitude to get the weather from OpenWeatherMap for the new location. I can't figure out what to pull from the results.

First: the JSON data:

```
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Tbilisi",
               "short_name" : "Tbilisi",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Didi digomi",
               "short_name" : "Didi digomi",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Tbilisi",
               "short_name" : "Tbilisi",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Georgia",
               "short_name" : "GE",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Tbilisi, Georgia",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 41.8438937,
                  "lng" : 45.0176811
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 41.6210248,
                  "lng" : 44.6600246
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 41.7151377,
               "lng" : 44.827096
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 41.8438937,
                  "lng" : 45.0176811
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 41.6210248,
                  "lng" : 44.6600246
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJa2JP5tcMREARo25X4u2E0GE",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

then my code, where I am able to get the STATUS fine, but I can't figure out how to change it to get the Latitude and Longitude:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

                request.open('GET',link,true);
                request.onload = function(){
                var obj2 = JSON.parse(this.response);
                if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {

                var newLat = (obj2.status);
                document.write(obj2.status);
               // var newLng = (obj2.results.formatted_address);
                alert(newLat);
```

This results in an alert of "OK" and the document having "OK" being written on it, but when I try to change it to pull the latitude and longitude data, it freaks out.

Please help.

Comment: It looks to me like you want to pull the lat/lng from `obj2.results[0].geometry.location.lat` and `obj2.results[0].geometry.location.lng`

Comment: Yes, that's perfect thank you. Can you explain why it need the [0]?

Comment: Of course. The `results` property of your JSON is an array. In the example you provided, it happens to only contain one item, but even if it had multiple, I assume Google would put the best match first in the array, which you can access by its index. The first item in an array in javascript and most languages is at index 0, hence the [0] in my example. If you wanted the second item in the array, you'd put [1], the third would be [2], etc.